# Console.WriteLine does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana) guide to self host owin in a console application. My problem is, after creating a project and adding all the nugets, when I copy and paste the program code I get "The type or namespace name 'WriteLine' does not exist in the namespace 'Console'" Anyone knows what's causing the issue? I'm targeting framework 4.7.2.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start<Startup1>("http://localhost:9000"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press [enter] to quit...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change your namespace `Console` to something else. E.g., `namespace ConsoleApp1`, `namespace MySelfHostedOwin`, etc.

Comment: ... or add the `System` namespace to your two code lines that are trying to use the `System.Console` class

Comment: `System.Console.WriteLine("Press [enter] to quit...");`
`System.Console.ReadLine();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change this `namespace Console` your app has **Console** namespace it shouldn't be like that

Example

```
namespace ChangeThisNameToAnotherOne

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start<Startup1>("http://localhost:9000"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press [enter] to quit...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you! I thought I can just leave that as the name of the project. I guess not. First time working with OWIN and ASP.net in general. Thank you!